# Converting .stl or .vtk file to JSON

Tags: json, converters, vtk, xtk, stl-format

I've been looking for ways how to convert vtk or stl files to json. 
I'm asking because I want to load my 3d models to web browser using https://github.com/xtk/X XTK library. But the vtk/stl files are too large (about 100 MB) to be displayed on the web.

I've read that the best solution is to write the model to JSON file.

I found this converter http://tmpvar.com/tmp/stl-json.html ,but the same problem occurs (too large size of the model).

Answer (score 1):

Assimp (Open Asset Importer) may be what you need:
http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Here is a tool that implements conversion to json directly: https://github.com/acgessler/assimp2json 
It has both source code and windows binaries.

Comment: please write important topics from the link here ,in case the link goes down.